# Intellij Project Structure: Configure PHP SDK

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

starting with Intellij 13.1 which was released today, it is possible to configure additional SDKs in the **Project Structure** dialoge. While the old 13.0 version only contained the following three items when clicking on the new button:

- JDK
- IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK
- Mobile SDK

The new 13.1 update has added several more options as can be seen on the screenshot:
[image]

When I click on **PHP Interpreter** then a directory chooser opens and ask me for the "Select Home Directory for PHP Interpreter". **Which folder is the correct one under Ubuntu?**

I have tried `/usr/bin` and I get a message that says: *Probably SDK installed in '/usr/bin' is corrupt*, and when I choose another directory then the message says: *The selected directory is not a valid home for PHP Interpretor*.[image]

However, when I go to **Settings->PHP** I have already correcly configured PHP 5.4 and when I open the details by clicking on '...' then I see the following:

[image]

Has anyone tried this? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in IntelliJ maybe?

Comment: may be your php version not detect IntelliJ. So this problem occur.

Comment: Another thing u already installed apache2 ?

Comment: My setup is complete with apache and mysql, I can open the website in the browser with no problem.

Comment: oky so you manually select `/usr/bin` directory instead of auto detect.

Comment: Then I get the message 'Probably SDK installed in 'usr/bin' is corrupt' as I wrote above.

Comment: yes i know. but i m saying to you manually set php interpreter path. but you already do this. oky check this http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Configuring_PHP_development_environment_on_Ubuntu#Downloading_and_Installing_the_Apache_HTTPD_Server

Comment: How is this related to apache? Anyway my apache is already working as I can access the web site from the browser.

Comment: Same Problem here on Kubuntu. But... I have also installed phpstorm. There is no SDK-Setting. Question is: Does this php-Interpreter Setting is needed... and if yes, what for?

Answer (score 3):

Open a new local shell/terminal window and type `which php`
this will tell you where the php binary is installed

in some ubuntu releases the repo's install php as php5, if that is the case you might need an `ln -s` to php

Although in my PhpStorm (PS-138.2071) it looks like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is done on settings level. Don't do it in project sdk level. Got to settings, look for php. Choose PHP language level and intellij will scan and get the interpreter for you